# How can I get access to a Spring context in a org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I tried using putting it into the constructor or doing this

```
@Override
protected void prepareForUse(SessionFactoryOptions settings, Map configValues) {

    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

}
```

but no luck as the WebApplicationContext is not started yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just plopped a check for it in every storage access operation.  So now I'm able to replace the use of Redisson which was causing

> MOVED redirection loop detected in cluster mode

And the added annoyance that I had to be replicate the configuration that was already available in Spring.  Including the cluster/single node and tracing and pooling.

Anyway here's the code I used to enable Spring's Redis Connection to provide the L2 Hibernate Cache.  It's pretty simple once you get over the hump of figuring out the lifecycle of the region factory in relation to Spring.  There's still the initial hit on start up before the context is created but once the app is running and the context is available it injects Redis and allows access.

```java
public class SpringRedisRegionFactory extends RegionFactoryTemplate {

    private transient Set<DomainDataStorageAccess> storageAccesses;

    @Override
    protected DomainDataStorageAccess createDomainDataStorageAccess(
        DomainDataRegionConfig regionConfig,
        DomainDataRegionBuildingContext buildingContext) {

        return registerNewStorageAccess(regionConfig.getRegionName());
    }

    @Override
    protected StorageAccess createQueryResultsRegionStorageAccess(String regionName, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {

        return registerNewStorageAccess(regionName);

    }

    @Override
    protected StorageAccess createTimestampsRegionStorageAccess(String regionName, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory) {

        return registerNewStorageAccess(regionName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareForUse(SessionFactoryOptions settings, Map configValues) {

        storageAccesses = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    }

    private DomainDataStorageAccess registerNewStorageAccess(final String regionName) {

        if (storageAccesses == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("prepareForUse was not executed yet");
        }
        final var storageAccess = new SpringRedisStorageAccess(regionName);
        storageAccesses.add(storageAccess);
        return storageAccess;

    }

    @Override
    protected void releaseFromUse() {

        storageAccesses.forEach(DomainDataStorageAccess::release);

    }

}
```

```java
@Slf4j
public class SpringRedisStorageAccess implements DomainDataStorageAccess {

    private final byte[] cacheRegionBytes;

    private final Map<Object, byte[]> serializationCache = new WeakHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    public SpringRedisStorageAccess(String cacheRegion) {

        this.cacheRegionBytes = cacheRegion.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    }

    /**
     * @param o object
     * @return byte array representation
     */
    private static byte[] toByteArray(Object o) {

        try (final var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             final var oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out)) {
            oos.writeObject(o);
            return out.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param bytes byte array representation
     * @return object or null if there's an error
     */
    private static Object toObject(final byte[] bytes) {

        try (final var is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
             final var ois = new ObjectInputStream(is)) {
            return ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IO Exception deserializing", e);
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("Class Not Found Exception deserializing", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object key) {

        return getOptionalRedisConnection()
            .map(RedisConnection::hashCommands)
            .map(hashCommands -> hashCommands.hExists(cacheRegionBytes, toByteArrayCaching(key)))
            .orElse(false);

    }

    private Optional<RedisConnection> getOptionalRedisConnection() {

        if (redisConnectionFactory != null) {
            return Optional.of(redisConnectionFactory.getConnection());
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext())
            .map(context -> {
                SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
                return redisConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            });


    }

    @Override
    public void evictData() {

        getOptionalRedisConnection()
            .map(RedisConnection::keyCommands)
            .ifPresent(keyCommands -> keyCommands.del(cacheRegionBytes));

    }

    @Override
    public void evictData(Object key) {

        getOptionalRedisConnection()
            .map(RedisConnection::hashCommands)
            .ifPresent(hashCommands -> hashCommands.hDel(cacheRegionBytes, toByteArrayCaching(key)));

    }

    @Override
    public Object getFromCache(Object key, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) {

        return getOptionalRedisConnection()
            .map(RedisConnection::hashCommands)
            .map(hashCommands -> hashCommands.hGet(cacheRegionBytes, toByteArrayCaching(key)))
            .map(SpringRedisStorageAccess::toObject)
            .orElse(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void putIntoCache(Object key, Object value, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) {

        getOptionalRedisConnection()
            .map(RedisConnection::hashCommands)
            .ifPresent(hashCommands -> hashCommands.hSet(cacheRegionBytes, toByteArrayCaching(key), toByteArray(value)));
    }

    @Override
    public void release() {

        getOptionalRedisConnection()
            .ifPresent(RedisConnection::close);

    }

    /**
     * Specific optimization for keys that may be repeated.
     *
     * @param o object
     * @return byte array representation
     */
    private byte[] toByteArrayCaching(Object o) {

        return serializationCache.computeIfAbsent(o, SpringRedisStorageAccess::toByteArray);

    }

}
```